# String Split - Calculate length of individual splitted parts

Tags: apex, string

For a string like :

```
String strTest = '123456.78';
system.debug(StrTest.split('\\.'));
```

The result is

> USER_DEBUG [2]|DEBUG|(123456, 78)

How can I get the individual length of the splitted parts ?

Comment: what you like to see, can you update your question

Comment: do you want 5 and 2?

Answer (score 1):

The string `split()` method returns a `List<String>`, so getting the individual lengths is simply

1. Iterating over the returned list
2. calling `string.length()` on the individual strings

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. Logic is same as Derek's answer

```
String strTest = '123456.78';

List<String> str = strTest.split('\\.');

for(integer i=0;i<str.size(); i++)
{
    System.debug(str[i].length());
}
```